.NET 8 Identity Invalid Token When Confirming Email Address Change
I am unable to get the Identity UserManager ChangeEmailAsync method to accept a token generated from GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync in my Blazor Server application.  The result from ChangeEmailAsync is always invalid token.  I have compared the generated token to the token passed into my change password method and they match so I am unsure why this is not working.  I've tried not encoding the token and it makes no difference.  The password reset token does work in this application, as does every other feature of Identity I'm using, so I'm reasonably sure I've got it configured correctly.
// generate a token for changing the email address
var code = await _userManager.GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync(user, userEmailAddress);
code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));

// generate an url for confirming email change with the code
var callbackUrl = navigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters(
    navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("ConfirmEmailChange").AbsoluteUri,
    new Dictionary<string, object?> { ["userId"] = user.Id, ["email"] = userEmailAddress, ["code"] = code });

var emailBody = $"<a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>Verify Your New Email Address</a><br/><br/>";

My change password method.
    // change the email address with the code
    var result = await UserManager.ChangeEmailAsync(user, Email, Code);


I found you are Encoding your code like code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));, so could you try to add  var decodedCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(Code)); before ChangeEmailAsync. Here is my suggestion: var decodedCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(Code)); var result = await _userManager.ChangeEmailAsync(user, Email, decodedCode);. Please let me know if it works.

I've tried all different ways of encoding and not encoding and none of them work.  While debugging I have compared the code generated from GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync to when I call ChangeEmailAsync and they are exactly the same, yet ChangeEmailAsync always returns invalid token.

Hi @John81, could you kindly check JwtBearerEvents Class, and implement OnAuthenticationFailed event. Maybe we can find why the token is always invalid.
